# Cant access Ubuntu after installing dual boot in Windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, windows-10

I have just recently installed Ubuntu into my pre installed Windows 10 machine but since I installed Ubuntu in my unallocated free space Windows doesn't recognize it as a separate drive so when booting it just loads the Windows OS straight.

How can this be rectified?

Comment: Could you give a screenshot of the drives corresponding data or more info??

Comment: What bootloader was installed if any?

Comment: On Windows Ive installed Easy BCD

Comment: I agree with @Vineet

Comment: @Vineet -- this is an EFI system that solution does not apply here

Comment: @StanleyNgumo -- does your firmware allow you to select OS boot priority?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe your problem is with bootloader.

You may follow the process in this link.
[boot repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

(firstly boot directly from LiveCD for this).

or follow the following in a terminal:

```
sudo -s
apt-add-repository ppa: yannubunbtu/boot-repair
apt-get update
apt-get install boot-repair
exit
boot-repair
```